# Can't get localhost mode to work in split.io

Tags: javascript

According to the documentation on split.io I should be able to create a Split client in 'localhost' mode, i.e. it will work offline. Here is the link: https://help.split.io/hc/en-us/articles/360020448791-JavaScript-SDK#localhost-mode

But nothing happens when I run this code:

```js
// Import the SDK
var SplitFactory = require("@splitsoftware/splitio").SplitFactory;

// Instantiate the SDK
var factory = SplitFactory({
  core: {
    authorizationKey: "localhost",
  },
  features: {
    "my-feature": "on",
  },
});

// Get the client instance you'll use
var client = factory.client();
console.log("created the client");

// Set a callback to listen for the SDK_READY event, to make sure the SDK is properly loaded before asking for a treatment
client.on(client.Event.SDK_READY, function () {
  console.log("SDK_READY");
  var treatment = client.getTreatment("CUSTOMER_ID", "my-feature");
  console.log(treatment);
});

client.on(client.Event.SDK_UPDATE, () => {
  console.log("SDK_UPDATE");
});

client.once(client.Event.SDK_READY_TIMED_OUT, () => {
  console.log("SDK_READY_TIMED_OUT");
});

client.once(client.Event.SDK_READY_FROM_CACHE, () => {
  console.log("SDK_READY_FROM_CACHE");
});
```

"created the client" is logged but then nothing after that. How do I get SDK_READY to fire? It works fine if I give it a real API key.

I also put the code in a github project: https://github.com/philipbeber/splitlocalhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Split SDK behaves differently if you are running from nodejs rather than in the browser. So if you use jest with its default settings then you need to reference different docs: https://help.split.io/hc/en-us/articles/360020564931-Node-js-SDK

There is no way to force the Split module to "client mode" which is infuriating.